# Overloading coffeescript get set method

Tags: coffeescript, overloading, getter-setter

I'm trying to overload a setter / getter value for a field called _name.  I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this in coffeescript, since this works but is very verbose.

```
class MyObject
  constructor: (@_defaultName) ->
  name: (colName) ->
    @_name = colName if colName?
    if @_name then @_name else @_defaultName
```

For the name method if the parameter is not set, then treat the method as a getter and return either the _name value or else the default if _name isn't set. I would like to have done something more like this, but I can't get it to work correctly:

```
class MyObject
  constructor: (@_defaultName) ->
  name: (@_name) -> if @_name? then @_name else @_defaultName
```

Does a pattern like this already exist? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  First, I'd like to point out that the `(@_name) ->` syntax does work outside of the constructor, but it will do bad things in this case if it is called as a getter (it'll clear `@_name` to `null`).  Here's how I would do this:

```
class A
  constructor: (@_defaultName) ->
  name: (_name) =>
    if arguments.length > 0
      @_name = _name
    else
      @_name ? @_defaultName
```

You'll get the same thing if you drop the `else` - that's just a style difference.  You can also do the one-line `if` if you want, but it feels like an awfully long line to me.

The `?` operator (`x ? y`) means `if @_name !== null then @_name else @_defaultName`.

As per @muistooshort's comment, I changed `_name?` to `arguments.length > 0`, which allows setting `@_name` to `null`.  However, note that setting it to `null` ("unsetting" it, perhaps) will cause it to revert to the default.

Comment: I think `if arguments.length > 0` is better than `if _name?` unless you intentionally want to disallow unsetting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `@` only works on parameters to the constructor, as far as I know. I'd stick with clarity here. It's not actually obvious from your code (either version) that you mean the function to be a getter and a setter. I'd go with something even *more* verbose than your original:

```
class MyObject
  constructor: (@_defaultName) ->
  name: (colName) ->
    if colName?
      @_name = colName
    else
      if @_name then @_name else @_defaultName
```

It seems so much more obvious what that is meant to do.

Comment: And if you want to be able to unset things with `o.name(undefined)` then you could look at `if(arguments.length > 0)` instead of `if(colName?)` and `if(@_name?)` instead of `if(@_name)` (the latter is a better idea in any case).